# Adding a .js to a Cordova Android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I use Eclipse Mars (4.5.1) with Android SDK 24.1.1. on Windows 7. I am upgrading a set of Cordova Android apps (now targeted at API 23 - Android 6) because of Google’s warning of blocking updates to pre-4.1.1 apps.

My apps use web-server-based pages entirely apart from the assets / www / index.html file that apart for the Cordova default header code contains  code of the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location=http://mydomain/mypage.html;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Since Cordova 6.0.0 with Android 5.1.0 specifics now has a “Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities” default option in index.htm, I moved the one line of Jscript (window.location=http://mydomain/mypage.html) to a separate file (say ‘pageopen.js’), added it to assets/www/js via Import / File System, and added a reference to it in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pageopen.js"></script>
```

All very straightforward…

However, when the app is run on the VDM, it fails saying that it cannot find index.js and res/xml/config.xml.
This failure is caused *just* by having the extra pageopen.js file in the js/ folder (I can remove the reference to it in index.html and the errors still occur). If I move pageopen.js to www/ (i.e. 'alongside' index.html), the app fails to find index.html instead!)

Having tried Refresh and Clean (Build automatically is ticked) with no effect, I am clearly doing something naïve and stupid. But what pls?